# Multiple labels with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Let's say that i have made a digital clock in my app, and i want to have 2 labels for seconds, 2 labels for minutes and 2 labels for hours and all of the labels had to run synchronously to give me the correct response. I guess i have to use NSDateFormatter and set the date format to each label, so it can represent one of the six digit numbers that will be shown all together in the six different labels. Does anyone know how i can do this?

It's kind of hard to explain, i hope this made any sense to you guys. Just ask if you want any further explanation of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  As close as I can understand you it is simply a matter of using multiple date formats and multiple invocations of NSDateFormatter.  What is your specific problem?

Comment: How can i have two different labels representing for example seconds? That's something that i find hard to figure out

Comment: I assumed you knew how to create labels.  Not clear why you need two labels, but why is it harder to set two than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [NSDateComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW1).

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [currentCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger hour = [components hour]; 
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];
```

Then if you want to split the components into two labels each, you can convert them to strings and get the `char` at index `0` and `1` (provided there are two digits).

---

**EDIT:**

Example to split the 2 digits of a component on two labels:

```
UILabel* label1;
UILabel* label2;

NSInteger hour = 2;

// so that it is always 2 (or more) characters long
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*d", 2, hour]; 

NSLog(@"<%@>", s);

NSString* s1 = [s substringToIndex:1];
NSString* s2 = [s substringFromIndex:1];

label1.text = s1;
label2.text = s2;
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show me the last part you said in code. I've never worked with NSDateComponent before